# create view with indexes

Tags: sql-server, view

I wanted to create a view, that will exhibit the same property as the table it queries from

```
CREATE VIEW Agent_View
AS 
SELECT * FROM Agent_table
```

I want to know if I need to create the same indexes as the **Agent_table** in the **Agent_View** also.

Do I need to declare the **Agent_View** as schemabound to create index. Is there any workaround to create indexes without declaring as schemabound ?

Comment: I don't think you need to create indexes on the View. The table's indexes will be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create indexes on the view with `SELECT *` because you can't have `WITH SCHEMABINDING`

A view without indexes is just a macro that expands into the outer query anyway. So table indexes will be used anyway. The view doesn't exist from a schema perspective.

Finally, IMHO this is possibly the most pointless use of a view possible. It adds **zero value**.

Answer (score 2):

Most (if not all) queries against this view will behave as if you used the underlaying table directly.

Thus if you indexed `agent_name` in `agent_table`, and performed a query like:

```
select *
  from agent_view
 where agent_name = 'James Bond';
```

...it would be rewritten by the optimizer to:

```
select *
  from agent_table
 where agent_name = 'James Bond';
```

Whether the index would be used or not is another question.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create indexed views if you have any complex queries, but in your case the table's indexes will be used.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)